# If SMP is disabled, does that mean I cannot use multicores? Or multiprocessors?

Tags: vps, smp, multi-core

I've purchased a VPS for the sake of dev work, and had wished to install NetBSD under the Xen DomU guest. Unfortunately it is stated that this will work, however will not support SMP.

Does this mean I cannot use the extra cores/processors that my VPS provides? I am unsure where SMP ties in to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-SMP OS will still run on a multi-core/CPU system, it just will not take full advantage of hardware capabilities of the setup.